# Rails - How do you make a nav link remain highlighted while on a specific page while still using application.html.erb to hold your navigation links?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

In Ruby on Rails(5) how do you make a nav link remain highlighted while on a specific page while still using application.html.erb to hold your navigation links?

For example:

**application.html.erb**

```
<nav class="nav">
    <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path, :class => 'na' %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Units", units_path, :class => 'ACTIVE' %></li> 
</nav>
```

Comment: This currently works to change the background as long as I'm on the index. The moment I go to the show it turns back. Any Ideas?

<li class="<%= 'active_bg' if current_page?(root_path) %>"><%= link_to "Home", root_path,%></li>

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something simple like:

```
<%= link_to 'Units', units_path, class: "#{'active' if controller_name == 'units' && action_name == 'index'}" %>
```